# Laravel S3, RDS, Redis, Mix - Usage

Tags: laravel, amazon-web-services, laravel-5

I have been working on an app for quite some time, however now I have realised that it is way too slow (Everything was on one server), so I have decided to 'split' it using AWS options that they provide so I have:

```
Amazon RDS - Used for database
S3 - Used for images/videos
Redis - Used for views and DB results?
Mix - Compile CSS/JS
Queue - For all the above + emails and long tasks
```

On top of that I am using Elastic Beanstalk to deploy, and auto scale instanced.

Now here's the questions:

1. Is this the right way to use all these services? i.e should I only use redis for Laravel blades and db results? Or I can use it for something else too?
2. Is there also a way where I could cache css/js so they get loaded faster?
3. Is there a way to optimize images using Laravel mix and then uploading them to s3?
4. Should anything else be stored as well?

Comment: Regarding caching css/js, optimizing images, as well as reducing load on your server have you looked at a CDN like CloudFlare?

Comment: I am actually using CloudFlare but I don't know much about it, don't know how to set that up, still I probably would want to set it up using those services, unless it has specific advantages

Comment: CloudFlare would be so much cheaper than all the AWS stuff you are proposing. You need to look into CloudFlare and setup everything you can there first. It will also serve cached files to the end users faster than your servers on AWS ever will.

Comment: well that it true but I am not paying for AWS, it is on the free tier at the moment, therefore I wanted to give it a go

Comment: Sure, but as soon as you scale up your EBS beyond one server it will no longer be free. Also you are stuck using really slow servers in free tier, which might be part of your speed issues.